# Deleting Cache won't get latest web page

Tags: asp.net, html, caching, browser-cache

I have a problem.

I have a mobile application (using HTML5 with localStorage). I have some web pages where theyare not cached but get the latest copy from what is on the webs server.

The problem that I am having is that one user regardless of deleting the cache still has an old copy of the program that resides on the server. Tried on a number of different browsers (Chrome, FireFox, IE) but still getting the same result. Just wondering if there is anything else I can do besides deleting the browser cache for it to realize that there is a more current version of the web page on the server

Comment: Does he have the site bookmarked? Some of the browsers have "Preserve Favorites" option in clearing cache

Comment: @YuriyGalanter- Thanks. How do I clear the cache in case there is a Preserver Favorites.

Comment: It's an option (at least in IE) you just have to uncheck it. In other browsers also pay attention to other options (like preserve offline etc.)